# how to set tooltip to htmlcontrol in codebehind in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have a html control like

```
<input id="Button1" type="button" value="button" />
      <input id="Text1" type="text" />
      <img alt="" src="" id="img1"  />
```

i want to set its tooltip or tittle in codebehind .

I tried the following code but its not working

```
  Button1.Attributes["tittle"] = "i am button";
   Text1.Attributes["tittle"] = "i am text";
  img1.Attributes["tittle"] = "i am image";
```

this is not working please help

Comment: "tiTTle..."? :-)

Answer (score 8):

Set `runat="server"` for each control:

```
<input id="Button1" runat="server" type="button" value="button" />
```

Then in CodeBehind in `Page_Load` use this:

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("title", "i am button");
```

Comment: Note: Button1.Attributes.Add("tittle".... Should be Button1.Attributes.Add("title"...  I tried to edit, but SO editing rules require at least six characters to be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark those elements as runat="server" so that the server knows about them. Otherwise, server-side code won't be aware that they exist.

Alternatively, you could add a blob of javascript to the response message body and have the JS set the attributes. That's silly and ugly, though.

Comment: i had marked the element as runat=server ,but still its not working